# putting ad to free android apps

Tags: android, ads

hi i have just finished making my android apps and would like to post to the android market as a free app, with an ad at the bottom. what are the necessary steps and required registrations for such?

1. does posting a free app need to pay that US$25 fee?
2. do i need to tell google a bank account and google would then handle the tax and give us the remaining to the account after tax and google's charged fee? (i am at Hong Kong)
3. admob seems to be an ad manager that put ad to the app. the website requires me to give the bank information also, what are these for? is it google or admob or both giving me revenue?
4. how is revenue calculated?
5. would there be any tax issues?
6. are there necessary codes amendments to my finished code?

Many thanks!

Comment: Good question - but not for stack overflow which must be pragramming related.

Comment: For #1: Yes, every developer pays that.

Comment: #6 : Yes you will have to add some code and some XML lines in your application for ads to be loaded and displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. It's the one-time Android app publisher registration fee.
2. No need to provide a bank account when you register as an app publisher if you only distribute free apps. But you need to provide it when registering at Admob.
3. Admob needs your bankaccount so they can pay you if you get enough clicks. Admob is owned by Google, but I think it's Admob that does the paying.
4. As far as I know Admob doesn't disclose how revenue is calculated. Check this [forum thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/73123-AdMob-statistics) for some examples on how much revenue other people got.
5. That depends on the tax laws in your country.
6. Yes, when you add Admob you need to add some code to your app.